# Spring MVC + Log4j

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, logging, log4j, slf4j

I'm trying to get Spring to log via log4j (and send that to graylog via gelf4j)

It just works when I'm in one of my spring batch applications. It doesn't work in a Spring Web application. So I googled that and found out you have to disable some commons logging and use a wrapper for slf4j. I put that in my code and now spring logs via log4j on a local tomcat (IntelliJ Debug). It doesn't work on my JBoss cluster though. Any ideas?

Here is my dependency setup:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.rest.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.data.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Web dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Testing dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.realityforge.gelf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>gelf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Utility -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And my log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=${build.logLevel}, default.out, default.file, gelf

# System.out.println appender for all classes
log4j.appender.default.out=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.default.out.threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.default.out.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.default.out.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %c: %m%n

log4j.appender.default.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.default.file.append=true
log4j.appender.default.file.file=${jboss.server.log.dir}/log-${build.environment}.log
log4j.appender.default.file.threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.default.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.default.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %c: %m%n

# Graylog appender
log4j.appender.gelf=gelf4j.log4j.GelfAppender
log4j.appender.gelf.host=127.0.0.1
log4j.appender.gelf.port=41337
log4j.appender.gelf.defaultFields={"app":"${project.artifactId}","environment":"${build.environment}","version":"${project.version}","buildTime":"${timestamp}","type":"java.log"}
log4j.appender.gelf.additionalFields={"exception": "exception", "loggerName": "loggerName", "threadName": "threadName"}
```

Comment: Your exclusion for `commons-logging` should be on the `spring-core` dependency not `spring-context` and you probably need a couple more. Also I don't see a dependency on log4j anywhere so where is that comming from?

Comment: slf4j-log4j12 has a dependency on log4j

Comment: You are right, however there was a bit more in my comment...

Comment: yep, let me try that

Comment: no commons-logging left in my dependencies, still no spring logs in my logfile

Comment: do a `mvn dependency:tree` see what you get in. Also JBoss uses a different logging approch (their own) so you might also have some classloading thingies going on.

Comment: "Also JBoss uses a different logging approch (their own) so you might also have some classloading thingies going on" that's it, i guess. wanna make an answer so i can accept that?